# Page not resizing in safari mobile when user opens a tab

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, mobile-safari

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but my app uses sencha touch 2.3.1, and the base element is a container with a 'vbox'.

Anyway, when the user loads the app in safari mobile while not having any tabs and then opening a new tab, the bottom of the page is now cut off. Also, the "resize" event is not fired, even though the innerHeight has been changed.

Does anyone know if this is a Sencha issue? Why the "resize" event isn't fired/how to detect the change?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your <body> tag has a position = fixed ? If yes, this looks like this is a browser bug so you should remove this.